# How to select specific column from parent and child in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Please see my code below.

**Controller**

```
$orders = Order::with('product:id,name')
    ->select([
            'id',
            'order_number',
            'ordered_on',
            'status',
            'total'
        ])
        ->where('customer_id', session('customer_id'))
    ->orderBy('ordered_on', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(6);
    dd($orders);
```

**Order model**

```
public function product()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

The result above returns `null` when you check the `product` relationship data.

**What I need**

Select specific columns from `Order` model, then select specific columns from `product` relationship.

Comment: inside the `->select()` u have to include the foreign key `product_id`

Comment: @ericmp woow, any reference with that? it is working now.

Comment: im hardly trying to find the docs on this but cant find it lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the foreign key that you are referencing:

```php
->select([
    'product_id'
    ...
])
...
```

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns